# Why does UIView show only the last view?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I have to show same view based on array data. So I am creating a view by using storyboard which will come below to each other. My code is below.

In .h file,

```
@interface Doctors : UIViewController{
NSMutableArray *dataarr;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *nameView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLbl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *Scroller;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ContentView;
```

In .m file

```
dataarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ram",@"Suresh",@"Anil", nil];
for (int i=0; i<dataarr.count; i++) {
    CGRect newframe = nameView.frame;
    nameLbl.text = [dataarr objectAtIndex:i];
    newframe.origin.y = nameView.layer.frame.origin.y + nameView.layer.frame.size.height;
    nameView.frame = newframe;
    [self.ContentView addSubview:nameView];
}
```

This code shows only the last view. I attached the screenshot below.
[image]

I am expecting to see this screen.

[image]

Why does it not show the first two views? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Because you're using only one view? So each time you change its content and frame?

Comment: Yes, I want to reframe the same view, but i am not getting the success

Answer (score 0):

Try like this 
**Updated**

```
float topMargin = 10;
for (int i=0; i<dataarr.count; i++) {
    nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(0,topMargin,320,40);
    nameLbl.text = [dataarr objectAtIndex:i];
    newframe.origin.y = nameView.layer.frame.origin.y + nameView.layer.frame.size.height;
    nameLbl.frame = newframe;
    [self.ContentView addSubview: nameLbl];
     topMargin+=yourHeight+10;
 }
```

Comment: check now  i change in this

Comment: Why you new alloc for nameLbl. I want to print View. Kindly Go through with my question one again.

Comment: then alloc your uiview and without allocing you can't reuse any View .. If  you want reuse any view you need to alloc must ....

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your code is not doing what you are expecting.

From your code, you only have one view and one label, your loop is only update your label text and the position of the view.

If you keep using story board, so you have to add two more "nameView" and two more "nameLbl".

However, we can do it programmatically without story board like that.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ram",@"Suresh",@"Anil", nil];

float yPosition = 50;

for (NSString *textString in dataArray) {
    //Alloc and add a view to your contentView
    UIView *viewToAddLabel = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosition, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];

    //Alloc new Label
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, viewToAddLabel.frame.size.width - 20, viewToAddLabel.frame.size.height - 10)];
    textLabel.text = textString;

    //Add your label to viewToAddLabel
    [viewToAddLabel addSubview:textLabel];

    //add viewToAddLabel To your content View
    [_contentView addSubview:viewToAddLabel];

    //Update your yPosition
    yPosition += 20 + viewToAddLabel.frame.size.height;
}
```